# OrientDB: containsall operator

Tags: document, fetch, orientdb, baasbox

I have collection of documents. Document have a field which value is an array of  maps (for example: map with one field `name`). Structure is like that:

```
{
  arrayfield: [
    {
       name: "value1",
    },
    {
       name: "value2",
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to fetch documents whose `arrayfieds` all maps contain values from specified array. Documentation says that I can use `containsall` operator. I use it in this way:

```
select from SomeCollection where arrayfiled containsall (name in ['value1','value2'])
```

But this construction always returns empty result. Where I do mistake? Thanks.

PS: If my question not understandable, I can post more detailed example of the collection and and a result which I want to receive.

Comment: What type is the property arrayfiled ?

Comment: Can you post the result of the following query "select from SomeCollection" ?
I would understand if arrayfiled is of type embedded, embeddedList, embeddedSet, emnbeddedMap, link, linkList, linkMap, linkSet

Comment: I can do it later. May be if it will help: I work with `baasbox` which uses OrientDB

Comment: @AlessandroRota here is the respond with I can get from baasbox: `[
  {"@rid":"#26:3",
    "@version":17,
    "@class":"SomeClass",
    "title":"some title",
    "arrayfield":[
      {"name":"value1"},
      {"name":"value2"}
    ],
    "projectid":"e251799e-8706-4eb8-a414-ad8524b00edb",
    "id":"7ebe866e-53a0-472d-96a1-98982e9ab274",
    "_allowRead":[{"@rid":"#4:4","@version":4,"@class":"ORole","name":"anonymous","isrole":true}],
    "_allowUpdate":[{"@rid":"#5:5","@version":1,"@class":"OUser","name":"bartl"}],
    "_allowDelete":["#5:5"],
    "_author":"bartl"}
  ]`

Comment: @AlessandroRota I used this request to determine the type of field: `select arrayfield.type() as type from SomeClass` and it returned `EMBEDDEDLIST`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution to solve my issue without containsAll:

`select from SomeCollection where not (arrayfield contains (fname not in ["value1", "value2"]))`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query

```
select from SomeCollection where arrayfiled.name contains "value1" and arrayfiled.name contains "value2"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it's not exactly what I need.  Let me describe the situation. I have the array of strings: [value1, value2, value3, ...] (from network request). And I need to query documents that satisfy next condition: **all** its elements in the `arrayfield` must have name from the passed array of strings. And length of the string array may be greater than the number of elements in the `arrayfield`

Comment: Query have to return rows 10:1, 10:2, 10:3 and 10:7 from your test example for input string array `["value1", "value2"]`.

Comment: Also I can modify `where` clause of the query in runtime, if it helps t solve this

Comment: To see if I have understood. For the case with only two parameters, the following query would work well?
select @rid,arrayfiled.name from (select expand($d)
let $a= ( select from SomeCollection where arrayfiled.name contains "value1" and arrayfiled.name contains "value2"),
    $b= (select from SomeCollection where arrayfiled.name contains "value1" and arrayfiled.size()=1),
    $c= (select from SomeCollection where arrayfiled.name contains "value2" and arrayfiled.size()=1),
    $d= unionAll($a,$b,$c))

Comment: Because it has the element with name=value3, which is not in the string array [value1, value2]. And I'm sorry, there is a mistake in the my second comment, querry should return 10:1 10:2 10.3, and should not 10:6 and 10:7. Replacng AND to OR will not help here.

Comment: try this query select @rid ,arrayfiled.name from someCollection where arrayfiled containsAll ( name = "value 1" or name="value 2" )

Comment: Wow, Why I didn't think about this variant ... It should work, I'll check it later. I let you know about the result. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Unfortunately, It does't work :(. Seems that containsAll isn't implemented at all, or I use this in wrong way :(